# Setting login based on user_type

Tags: php, authentication

I am working on a university project, which is based on e-shopping. I tried this code to implement my result, this gives an error and does not work - I think there's a mistake with the code there.

This code is from my login header:

```
<?php 
        if($_GET('user_type')='Administrator')

        !isset($_SESSION['txt_username']) || !isset($_SESSION['txt_pwd'])){
            echo "<a href='login.php'>Log in</a>";                                          
        }else{
            echo $_SESSION['txt_username'];
            echo ' &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a href="logout.php"> Log Out</a>';
            } 
        ?>
```

Comment: `this gives error` - so what is the error?

Comment: it shoes error in the code at Adobe DW

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax errors that are highly localised to the OP.

Comment: when you use a `$_GET` you need to use square brackets after it and not round ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you had some syntax issues:

```
<?php 
 //you will need this before you do anything with $_SESSION
 session_start(); 

   if(isset($_GET['user_type']) && $_GET['user_type'] == 'Administrator'){

      if( !isset($_SESSION['txt_username']) || !isset($_SESSION['txt_pwd']) ){

            echo "<a href='login.php'>Log in</a>";                                          

      }else{

            echo $_SESSION['txt_username'];
            echo ' &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a href="logout.php"> Log Out</a>';

      }  
   }
?>
```

Comment: thanks and let me try then i will return back to get more help thanks :)

Comment: @AliMirza see edit i had to fix some minor mistakes i made.

Comment: thanks a lot dude could you please me with my project ? please give me your skype id to have a chat with you for further guidance

Comment: Sorry, i don't give out personal information on Stack Overflow! If you get stuck just post a question on this website, some one can help. Also if this solved your problem please click the tick icon next to the answer :)

Comment: buddy i am using your suggested code on my Admin index page if user tries to loign it should remain on current page so what will the additional code required in it? thanks :)

Comment: You will need to perhaps use a &_SESSION and header / deny users who do not have `$_SESSION['admin'] = true;` which you can set to true upon user login by checking the database if they have admin rights. you'd be better off reading up on PHP documentation as these are very basic things which the manual can explain better than i.

Comment: +1 for not offering endless free support! OP, asking for email/chat details is discouraged here. If people offer them in their profile, then fine - otherwise just stick to asking good questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Issue in line below

```
     if($_GET('user_type')='Administrator')
```

Should be:

```
   if($_GET['user_type']=='Administrator')
```

Comment: Edit: he's edited his answer ;)